# Plotly Python graph click events

Tags: python, graph, plotly

I am using Plotly offline in Python and I want to add a simple click event, so when clicked on a point, a new web page opens. Is there any simple solutions for that? I have read a lot on that topic but all snipets are very complicated and I can not use them.

Comment: Are trying to build a stand-alone graph, or using plotly-dash or Jupyter notebook?

Comment: I am using plotly without dash. I am trying python an javascript. I succeeded to make click event in javascript but the problem with that is that in javascript I can not load too many points. In python I can load many points but the problem is the lack of events.

Comment: There are at least two possibilities: 1) load the data dynamically from Python, e.g. via a simple web server which serves data to your Javascript code or 2) use Plotly's Python widgets: https://plot.ly/python/mouse-events/